# how to add custom js function on facebook like button before like happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am new in this area, so my apologies for any inconvenience... I have to restrict my users to like one of my website contents once a day.
For that i have added facebook like button and this trigger:

```
     FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function (response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            });
```

but it is called after the user has clicked the like button, but i want a js function to work before like happens and check whether the user has liked today or not and if liked then cancel the like and reload; and if not already liked , then the like functionality goes smoothly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this code will make sense

```
//listen for user to click the LIKE button
$(document).on('click', 'targetFBbuttonHere', function(){
    //figure out if it is liked already
    if('ALREADY LIKED TODAY'){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        //Code to allow LIKE
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..
i have tried this code but facebook like button does not generate if i put like code in else...